# Create folder in a particular place via bat file

Tags: batch-file

i want to create a folder named Search in following path C:\Program Files\Search Engine Builder Standard\Projects\Search with batch file

Comment: i tried mkdir C:\Program Files\Search Engine Builder Standard\Projects\Search but it is not working when i tried this mkdir C:\Search it works
but i want it be created in C:\Program Files\Search Engine Builder Standard\Projects\

Comment: Does the directory where you want to create the new folder already exist? As the path has spaces are you quoting it? `mkdir "C:\Program Files\Search Engine Builder Standard\Projects\Search"` ?

Comment: I think you need to run the bat file as Administrator.

Comment: this is the path in C: program files of a win xp pc

Answer (score 2):

you need to enclose a path with spaces in doublequotes:

```
mkdir "C:\Program Files\Search Engine Builder Standard\Projects\Search"
```

Else `mkdir` will make several  directories. In your case:
`C:\Program` and  `Files\Search` and `Engine` and so on...

(and you need Admin-Rights do write to `program files`, as rriower already stated)

Comment: I TRIED THIS CODE BUT NOT WORKING I AM LOGGED AS ADMINISTRATOR how can i add this feature in batch file